# Looking for a good English-to-Hebrew translation software

Tags: hebrew, internet, technology, translation, language

I'm looking for a translation software, or website, that accurately translates entire sentences and paragraphs from English to Hebrew, without grammar mistakes or funny language usage. Anyone know of something that can help me?

Comment: learner, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! please consider registering your account which will give you access to enhanced site features.

Answer (score 3):

While Yossi Rozenman is right in that there is no software that accurately translates sentences with no grammar mistakes or funny usage, I am partial to Google Translate, located at [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com/) and with applications for Android and iPhone.

Comment: You could make your answer more valuable by explaining why you like Google Translate. Is it their Googly translation-by-correlation methods?

Comment: I, too, agree that a human is needed for accurate translation (though someone reading this in a couple of decades may laugh at that), but I, too, like Google's. I like that it offers alternative translations of polysemous words, which one than choose among by checking a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, Isaac, I appreciate that they are constantly learning and request feedback which they further incorporate.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such software or website. The only way to get an accurate translation is using a professional translator.

Comment: Yossi Rozenman, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this insight! You could make it even better by adding some information about the inherent shortcomings of machine translation. I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: PS: I see in your profile that you're a professional translator. I appreciate that you put a link to your website in your profile, where it belongs, rather than into the answer, where it doesn't. Of course, if you choose to elaborate your answer, please do feel free to refer to any relevant experiences or insights you've gathered as a translator.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a little experiment, and inserted text into google translate, and then had Bablyon reverse the translation.  I did the same again in reverse.  You can then compare the two translations, until you find something good. :)  Also helps you learn the language.

In the end however, you will need a professional to translate it properly.

Answer (score 1):

No such amazing software, but you may wish to try http://context.reverso.net/translation/
It is nice for translating short phrases.

Answer (score 0):

the best software for english to hebrew translation is Babylon - http://www.babylon.com/welcome/index.html?affID=109100

Comment: Rafi, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this reference! If you [edit] in some information about the advantages of this particular software, you could make your answer even more valuable. Also, please consider registering your account, to give you access to more of the site's features.